# How to select from multiindex based on individual values in several columns?

Tags: python, pandas, select, multi-index

I have a dataframe created like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ind1': list('AAABBBCCC'),
    'ind2': list(map(int, list('123123123'))),
    'val1': [0, 0, 0, -1, -4, 5, 10, 11, 4],
    'val2': [0.1, 0.2, -0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, -0.1, 2, 0.1]
})

df = df.set_index(['ind1', 'ind2'])
```

Resulting data:

```
           val1  val2
ind1 ind2            
A    1        0   0.1
     2        0   0.2
     3        0  -0.2
B    1       -1   0.1
     2       -4   0.2
     3        5   0.2
C    1       10  -0.1
     2       11   2.0
     3        4   0.1
```

I want to select all entries where:

1. At least one item in `val1` is unequal `0`
2. Each absolute value in `val2` is `< 0.5`

In the example above, therefore only

```
B    1       -1   0.1
     2       -4   0.2
     3        5   0.2
```

should remain.

I cannot use `sum()` as the values can be positive and negative, so something like this

```
df.reset_index().groupby('ind1').sum()

      ind2  val1  val2
ind1                  
A        6     0   0.1
B        6     0   0.5
C        6    25   2.0
```

would not work.

How would I use `any()` and `all()` here?

Comment: You're looking for all ind1 entries that satisfy the filter conditions?

Comment: @blueberryfields: Yes, that's the goal.

Comment: My error ... and now I've lost the actual duplicate.  You're just looking for a compound filter -- try a browser search on that phrase.

Comment: @Prune: No problem. If you find the actual duplicate, feel free to post it and close the question again. (and maybe also remove the downvote)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without lambda by `transform`

```
s1=df.val1.ne(0).groupby(level=0).transform('any')
s2=df.val2.abs().lt(0.5).groupby(level=0).transform('all')
df[s1&s2]
Out[583]: 
           val1  val2
ind1 ind2            
B    1       -1   0.1
     2       -4   0.2
     3        5   0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is via `groupby().filter()` ([link to docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html)), which evaluates a boolean condition on each group (as opposed to each DataFrame row):

```
df.groupby('ind1').filter(lambda x: x['val1'].any() & 
                                   (x['val2'].abs() < 0.5).all())

           val1  val2
ind1 ind2            
B    1       -1   0.1
     2       -4   0.2
     3        5   0.2
```

Note that `DataFrame.groupby.filter()` is unrelated to the same-named method `DataFrame.filter()`!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, similar to Wen's solution:

```
mask = df.abs().groupby(level=0).transform('max')
df[mask.val1.gt(0)&mask.val2.lt(0.5)]
```

Output:

```
           val1  val2
ind1 ind2            
B    1       -1   0.1
     2       -4   0.2
     3        5   0.2
```